# Clarification regarding a usage in matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, differential-equations

Suppose that I type the following code in matlab command window :

```
>> f=dsolve('D2y+y=0','y(0)=0',x)
```

So I get this :

```
>>f=
C22*sin(x)
```

Suppose from this I want to extract only 'sin(x)' without that C22 how do I do that ?? One more thing is I cannot add any more initial or boundary condition. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code substitues all variables except those in `vars_to_keep` with 1

```
syms x
f=dsolve('D2y+y=0','y(0)=0',x);
all_vars=symvar(f);
vars_to_keep=x;
set_to_one=setdiff(all_vars,vars_to_keep);
for ix=1:numel(set_to_one)
    f=subs(f,set_to_one(ix),1);
end
```